# XML Schema: complexType element not supported in this context

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I'm writing an .xsd file in order to generate a class that I can derive xml's out of. I've followed the tutorial at http://www.w3schools.com/schema/, but I can't seem to figure out one portion.
I would like to declare my own complex type (allocinfo) for use across multiple elements. What I can't figure out is where to declare it in my schema. I've declared it right before its first use below, but it gives me an error that it is not available in this context. I've also tried to declare it in the beginning of the schema, but then my nested elements cannot see it.

```
<xs:element name="Payload">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name ="Alloc">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>

          <xs:complexType name="allocinfo"> //custom type
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="firstInfo"/>
              <xs:element name="secondInfo"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>

          <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:allocinfo"/> //allocinfo is the custom type in question
          <xs:element name="Length" type="xs:integer"/>
          <xs:element name="Dir" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="MsgType" type="xs:string" />
          <!--Figure out how to restrict on set of values-->
          <xs:element name="MsgSubType" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="MsgTime" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <!--End TmsTmh-->
```

If someone has experience in defining and utilizing their own complex types, can you point out where I'm going wrong?
If I can provide more clarification or code, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give your complexType definition a name, in order to refer to that name from an element definition. Also, if your complex type has a name, it must appear as a subelement of `<xs:schema>`. Take a look at this schema definition :

```
<xs:schema>
  <xs:element name="Alloc" type="AllocType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="AllocType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <!-- more to follow here -->
```

Note the slash at the end of the element definition. Also note that the complex type definition does not have to be before the element definition.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! I edited my code to match your suggestion. I'm still receiving an error, from which it seems to be saying that my complex type is a child element of a sequence element, and that is not allowed for some reason. Have you ran into this before? I tried declaring it outside the sequence element above it, but still errors.

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept the answer to show other readers that it helped to fix your problem.